# reading file and storing data in python

Tags: python

I have a text file which has data in following format:

```
*NODE
   5100387,  54.799831647418,  -4.147024550067,  22.466648807633
*ELEMENT,TYPE=C3D10M,ELSET=HEAD-R
   5446424,   6192081,   5849509,   5849511,   6182919,   6820540,   5210471,  6611315,
   6611314,   6459296,   6611316
```

I want to read this file and store node information in a node tuple and element information in a element tuple.

```
node = (5100387,  54.799831647418,  -4.147024550067,  22.466648807633)
element = (5446424,   6192081,   5849509,   5849511,   6182919,   6820540,   5210471,  6611315, 6611314,   6459296,   6611316)
```

and store element type and elset in variables.

Thanks.

*Please see there is a break in element information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regular expression.

```
r"\*NODE\n(.+\n)\*ELEMENT.+\n(.+\n.+)"
```

To utilize this regex you will need to pass the [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) flag.

```
regex = re.compile(r"\*NODE\n(.+\n)\*ELEMENT.+\n(.+\n.+)", re.MULTILINE)
```

This regex will capture two groups, which we utilize to build your `node` and `element` tuples.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"\*NODE\n(.+\n)\*ELEMENT.+\n(.+\n.+)", re.MULTILINE)
record = """*NODE
   5100387,  54.799831647418,  -4.147024550067,  22.466648807633
*ELEMENT,TYPE=C3D10M,ELSET=HEAD-R
   5446424,   6192081,   5849509,   5849511,   6182919,   6820540,   5210471,  6611315,
   6611314,   6459296,   6611316"""

matches = re.match(regex, record)

nodes = tuple([x.strip() for x in matches.group(1).split(",")])
elements = tuple([x.strip() for x in matches.group(2).split(",")])
```

---

We utilize each capture group to build a list of `nodes` and `elements`. This is accomplished with these two lines:

```
[x.strip() for x in matches.group(1).split(",")]
[x.strip() for x in matches.group(2).split(",")]
```

We split the captured string on commas (`,`) and then strip white space from each element. At the end of the above lines, we what two sets of lists. The first (`group(1)`) contains the `nodes`. The second (`group(2)`) contains the `elements`.

Finally, since it was requested that these are tuples, we convert the list to tuples by wrapping the list comprehension. Side note: You may not actually need these to be tuples, a list could work just as well depending on what the rest of your application does and expects.

---

The `nodes` and `elements` contain these values after running the above code.

```
('5100387', '54.799831647418', '-4.147024550067', '22.466648807633')
('5446424', '6192081', '5849509', '5849511', '6182919', '6820540', '5210471', '6611315', '6611314', '6459296', '6611316')
```

Comment: *NODE
       5100387,  54.799831647418,  -4.147024550067,  22.466648807633
       5100388,  54.523871941378,  -4.24224191018 ,  22.140150249475
    *ELEMENT,TYPE=C3D10M,ELSET=HEAD-R
       5446424,   6192081,   5849509,   5849511,   6182919,   6820540,   5210471,   6611315,
       6611314,   6459296,   6611316
       5446425,   5844024,   6202612,   5844023,   6187467,   7136510,   6703233,   5152584,
       6399988,   6896934,   6616950

Can we also apply this in multiple lines of data of each node and element. I am trying to do it but not able to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use open() to read the file as a string into python. Then you can parse the string for the information you want and store it in the appropriate variables.

[Read more about open.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)